# Why SQL Server index is not used?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Most of my SQL queries have `WHERE rec_id <> 'D';` as for example:

```
 select * from Table1 where Field1 = 'ABC' and rec_id <> 'D'
```

I added index on `REC_ID`.  But when I run this query and look at the execution plan, the new index `(REC_ID)` is not used.  The Execution plan shows Cost of 50% of nonClustered index `Field1` and `50% RID Lookup` (Heap) in `Table1`.

Why the index `REC_ID` not used?

Comment: How are your indexes defined?  You may want to add an `INCLUDE (Field1)` to your `rec_id` index definition.

Comment: How many rows in the table?What is the cardinality,the proportion of rows returned to the total number of rows?

Comment: You could also try if using the index even helps, turn on statistics io and use index hint to force SQL Server to use it

Comment: @Siyual I am not familiar with the INCLUDE syntax; I will have to learn how to use it.  Thank you.

Comment: @Mihai  The table has approximately 300,000 rows.

Comment: 50% RID Lookup (Heap) ?  Is you table a heap ?  If so the engine behaves very differently than expected on tables with no clustered indexes.

Comment: @JamesZ forcing an index hint won't change the fact that the index currently doesn't have the rest of the fields in it and will need to still go to the heap and pull the other fields.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer Yeah, but you can't really put everything there (this is select *), but Field1 might help, assuming there's significant percentage of other values too

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna  I am a newbie so I will have to learn how to add a clustered index to this table.  thank you.

Comment: @Hidalgo Given that you have 300K rows you should probably have a clustered index.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna  The table has a primary key nonclustered and I understand that I would need to change this primary key to clustered (please correct me if I am wrong). Thank you.

Comment: Since you're using `SELECT *`, you want to get **all columns** from that table - so ultimately, SQL Server will have to read the entire data page anyway. So depending on how many rows (out of your 300'000) are matched by your criteria, the query optimizer might just conclude that using the index isn't worth it.... What if you use `SELECT REC_ID .....` instead? Is the index used then?

Comment: @marc_s  If I understand your question, if I put the REC_ID expression before the Field1 = 'ABC', it does not make a difference.  
Thank you.

Comment: No, I meant - what if you run ` select rec_id from Table1 where Field1 = 'ABC' and rec_id <> 'D'` (instead of `select * ....`)  - does the index get used in that case?

Comment: @marc_s no difference.  The only time I see the difference is (as you correctly pointed) that if instead of * (all) I select just one field (e.g. Field1) I see both indexes being used.

Comment: Also: your table really should have a **clustered index** - this would speed up just about all operations (compared to a heap) - see Kimberly Tripp's excellent [The Clustered Index Debate continues....](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/) blog post for background info and reasoning

Comment: @marc_s  Yes, I will create clustered index; I just need to think on how to do it without breaking anything else.  Thank you for the link to the article.

Answer (score 3):

For this query:

```
select *
from Table1
where Field1 = 'ABC' and rec_id <> 'D';
```

The best index is `table1(Field1, rec_id)`.

However, your query may not be able to take advantage of an index.  The goal of using an index for a `where` clause is to reduce the number of pages that need to be read.  To understand the concept for non-clustered indexes on normal rows, you need some basic ideas:

- Records are stored on pages.
- Each page is 8,192 bytes (slightly fewer used for data) and can store some number of records.
- The entire page is loaded into memory to read a record.

Say a record is about 80 bytes and there are 100 records on each page.  If 10% of the records have `Field1 = 'ABC'`, then there will be about ten on each page.  That means that using the index would not (typically) save any page reads.  If 1% of the records match, then there is about one on each page.  The index still isn't helpful.

If only 0.01% of the records match (30 in your case), then only a fraction of the pages need to be read.  This is the sweet spot for indexes, and where they are really helpful.

The number of matching records is called "selectivity".  If the `where` clause is not very selective, then a non-clustered index will not be useful.

Sometimes, a clustered index can be helpful in this situation.  However, clustered indexes may have more overhead for `insert` and certain `update` transactions.  So, the choice of index needs to be based on the queries being processed and other ways that the table is used.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff  My understanding is that clustered index will have an advance (not always but often) when reading data and the disadvantage when writing (sometimes).  Since I am mostly concerned with reading, I will change my PK index to clustered.  In my experience a user usually puts down the coffee cup and clicks on Get Me My data with the thought "I want it now!"  When they click on Save, they reach for the coffee cup and don't mind waiting {bg}

Comment: @Hidalgo . . . A clustered index on `Field1, rec_id` might help you.  This should reduce the number of pages being loaded.  However, it sounds like the query may be returning many, many rows.  If so, just the volume of data may be a significant part of the performance issue.

Comment: @ Gordon.  The example in my initial post with Field1 was a simplified case.  When I converted the PK to clustered and ran a different query, the execution plan showed that this PK clustered index was used.  So this is what I need to do.  Thank you.

Comment: @Hidalgo . . . Cool.  There are definitely cases where clustered indexes benefit performance.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses many factors to decide which indices to use.  It must have determined that using the index on `Field1` would be more effective that using the index on `rec_id` - meaning that `field1={value}` defines a smaller set than `rec_id <> {value}` based on data dispersion, etc., so there are fewer records to compare against the other condition.  Note that the actual value is usually irrelevant in determining which index to use.

Comment: @ D Stanley.  I just ran a query again with a different value than 'ABC' and the execution plan shows 100% Table1 Table Scan; index Field1 is not used at all.  I was just deciding if it would be worthwhile adding index REC_ID but the results are not conclusive.  Thank you.

Comment: @Hidalgo A query will only use one index on a table, so adding another simple index won't help unless the index on that field results in a better plan than the index on the initial field. Adding a _composite_ index might help, but again it all depends on what SQL server thinks is the most optimal plan (and it's not always right).

Comment: @ D Stanley.  I see what you mean. I added a composite index and it is being used. But then I removed composite index, changed the PK to clustered (it was nonclustered) and I see an improvement. 
Thank you.